# Function doesn't recognize condition from another function

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```js
function checkDuplicity(){
  for (var i = 0; i < newCombination.length; i++) {
    if(JSON.stringify(newCombination[i]) == localStorage.getItem("test")){
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

When I check this function in DevTools, it returns proper boolean, when the condition is met or isn't met.

I use this function **here as condition of executing function**.

```js
function makeId(){
  if(storedDate != null){
    if (checkDuplicity()) {
      localStorage.setItem("combination"+(localStorage.length+1), JSON.stringify({ 
          movie: storedMovie,
          date: storedDate,
          time: storedTime
      }));
    }
}}
```

**Even though I check output of checkDuplicity() in DevTools and its false - function above is still executed.**

Thank you

This is how newCombination is filled in:

```js
var newCombination = []

function pushingInForm() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= localStorage.length; i++) {
    if ((localStorage.getItem('combination' + i) != null)) {
      var push = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("combination" + i));
      newCombination.push(push);
    } else {
      //
    }
```

Comment: Maybe something changed in local storage between the time you tested in DevTools and when the function was run.

Comment: Or maybe the `newCombination` array changed.

Comment: What is the datatype of `newCombination[i]`? If it's an object, the result of `JSON.stringify()` may not be consistent -- properties can be in different orders.

Comment: I just added - console.log(checkDuplicity()); before the condition and it returns bad boolean.

Comment: @Barmar its array of objects

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `makeId()`. Does it enter the `if`?

Comment: As I said, comparing JSON is not a valid way to compare objects.

Comment: What is a "bad boolean"?

Comment: You shouldn't use stuff like `"combination"+(localStorage.length+1)` as item name for localStorage. Store the entire stringified array as a single LS item.

Comment: Is it correct that `checkDuplicity()` is checking a different `localStorage` item than the ones you create in `makeId()`?

Comment: Here's code that attempts to reproduce the problem but fails: https://jsfiddle.net/wa8u0bch/# (I renamed the function to clarify what it does)

Comment: What happens if you also put `console.log("storing combination")` inside the `if`? Do you see it log `false` and then `storing combination`?

Comment: @Barmar yes, I try to avoid duplicating items in LS with this checkDuplicity() - when it compares to localStorage.getItem("test") it shouldn't be saved into LS. It means that certain situation won't happen two times and won't be two times saved into LS - by bad boolean I mean, that it returns opposite - in console.log - just right before if() of what it shows me in DevTool.

Comment: That means something is changing between the time you check in DevTools and when the function is run in the application. How does `newCombination` get filled in? Is there AJAX involved?

Comment: @Barmar I added that into question. And its executed like that - > 

makeId();

pushingInForm();

Comment: @Barmar inside which `if` do you mean?

Comment: `localStorage.length` counts items in `localStorage` that aren't `combinationX`.

Comment: The second `if`. Because you claimed that the function is returning `false` but it's going into the `if` anyway. I wanted to prove that this isn't true.

Comment: How do you call `pushingInForm()`? Is it called asynchronously?

Comment: @Barmar I call it straight in the code under functions in this order -> 1. `makeId();` 2. `pushingInForm();`

Comment: If you call `makeId()` first, there won't be any duplicates, because `pushingInForm()` fills in `newCombination`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks...that actually helped, but now I need to refresh page 2 times to fill it into newCombination = []

Comment: It's really hard to understand this out of the full context of the application. But I can assure you that `if` is not broken the way you think it is. The problem you're having is simply that the state that `checkDuplicity()` tests is different when you call it in DevTools and when the application calls it, because things are changing over time.